# php regex or | operator

Tags: php, regex

I am doing a preg_replace:

```
$pattern = '/<ul>/';
$replacement = "";
$string = "hello <ul> how are you doing </ul>";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

That will replace my `<ul>` with `""` but Id like to replace anything that is a `<ul>` or `</ul>`, I am not getting how to use the `|` (or) character though.

I try like this, but it is not working right:

```
$pattern = '/<ul>|</ul>/';
$replacement = "";
$string = "hello <ul> how are you doing </ul>";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Any help would be surely appreciated

Thanks,
Bryan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may need to escape the slash in /ul like this:

```
$pattern = '/<ul>|<\/ul>/';
```

or do this, not sure if it'll work:

```
$pattern = '/<\/?ul>/';
```

(the '?' means zero or one of the previous characters, which is '/' in this case.)

Comment: Another option is to use a different regex delimiter: `'~</?ul>~'`

Comment: <\/?ul> is a good one, and finally solved a regex bug I've been dealing with. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the backslash.

`/<ul>|<\/ul>/`