# Regular expression, create pattern various options, is possible?

Tags: php, regex

I'm searching inside an html code a specific string starting or containing, for example "name:" with this:

```
$r = '/name.*/';
preg_match_all($r,$body, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

But I can find "name" in at least 3 different languages, so, is it possible to create this pattern with three options instead of searching 3 times? something like "or"? (regex is under PHP)

Comment: there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743329/php-regex-or-operator use the OR operator to match multiple cases.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!!! THANKS! so it should be something like: $pattern= 'patternA|patternB';

Comment: Yes `$r = '/name1|name2|name3/';` should work.

Comment: Yup, both solutions proposed here and in the comment below actually works. Feel free to use the one you like the most, even though defining a pattern like Steve Chambers did is probably the way you should take :)

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate what was said in the comments in an answer (so this doesn't appear as unanswered in searches) + including parentheses (to allow the wildcard to be added once at the end):

Assuming the names are "name1", "name2" and "name3", change your `$r` definition to:

```
$r = '/(name1|name2|name3).*/';
```